# Upload images using MultiPart

Tags: ios, multipart

I am creating an app where i have to upload image using MultiPart (File-Type) which I am getting from the gallery. Can anyone tell me how to do it. How would I pass the parameter with that image.  I searched a lot but didn't find any solution. 
My code is like:-

```
 NSURL *baseUrl=[NSURL URLWithString:baseUrlStringForUserRegisterPage];    
    NSDictionary *parameters=@{@"pic":_imageViewUserSignUpView.image};  
    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];  
    manager.responseSerializer=[AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];  

    [manager POST:baseUrlStringForUserRegisterPage parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData)  
     {  
     }  
         progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject)  
     {  
     }  
          failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error)  
     {  
     }];
```

baseUrlStringForUserRegisterPage carry my URL. I am using AFNetworking here.

Answer (score 1):

this is how it should work:

```
NSURL *baseUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:baseUrlStringForUserRegisterPage];

// use parameters for other parameters than the images - if needed
// NSDictionary *parameters = @{};

AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

// prepare your image(s)
UIImage *imageToUpload = _imageViewUserSignUpView.image;
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageToUpload);
// NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageToUpload, 0.75) // if you want to upload jpeg instead of png

[manager POST:baseUrlStringForUserRegisterPage parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"pic" fileName:@"pic.png" mimeType:@"image/png"];
    // [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"pic" fileName:@"pic.png" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"]; // if you want to upload jpeg instead of png
} progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"success");
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
    NSLog(@"failure");
}];
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But it is not getting save. I did so :-   
 (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    _imageViewUserSignUpView.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

imageConversionToData=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(_imageViewUserSignUpView.image, 0.75);
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

And i am using imageConversionToData(NSData) further. Please suggest me.